# Detect user clicks on push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

If the user clicks on the icon, then the application starts with the start page. How can I make sure that the user clicked on the push notification to launch the application with another start page?

Comment: are you using firebase push notification?

Comment: You want to detect the the user tap on your notification and then you want to redirect the user to see a specific page..am i right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using firebase push notification. Yes, I want to redirect the user to see a specific page in application or run application with specific page as main page

Comment: ok. posted answer. please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken;
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Registration failed!")
}

// Firebase notification received
// This function will work app is in foreground state
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    if notification.request.content.userInfo["cook"] != nil{
        return;
    }
    print(notification.request.content.userInfo)
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       // add some code here..
       // window?.rootViewController = LoginController()

       // If you use the storyboard, then you can get controller by
       // storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifier") as! UIViewController
    }
}

// This function will work app is in state of background or closed.
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you  can check if this is from closed or background
    print("Handle push from background or closed\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    if response.notification.request.content.userInfo["somevariable"] != nil{
        return;
    }
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       // add some code here..
    }

}
```

Please use this this code into AppDelegate.swift

> Please see the function called userNotificationCenter and comments in
>   code.

Comment: How can I go to specific page?

Comment: that depends on your app. we can make some viewcontroller as root.
window?.rootViewController = SomeController()

Answer (score 2):

Ok..i will make it simple for you.

**First step-**

Add this function inside your `AppDelegate` file.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

      print("Hi Kirill...")

    }
```

If you add this in your `AppDelegate` file, after running your app when you tap on the notification you will see this on your debugger, .
Like this -

[image]

And finally, to show a specific page in application add this inside the function.

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: " Your view controller identifier name") as! yourViewControllerClassName 
        window?.rootViewController = otherVC;
```

It will look like this -

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

          print("Hi Kirill...")

          let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: " Your view controller identifier name") as! yourViewControllerClassName 
          window?.rootViewController = otherVC;

        }
```

Make sure you add a another `viewController`, what you want to `redirect/show` when you tap on the notification. Thank you.